# iPadのwebブラウザにおけるペンと指の反応の違いが技術的にあるんでしょうか

Tags: javascript, ios, firefox, rstudio

iPad Air 4, FirefoxにてRstudio Serverというwebアプリに接続しています。

指だとテキストエディタやターミナルが反応するのですが、Apple Pencilの互換品では反応せずカーソルが表示されませんでした。
なお、Code Serverであれば両方いけました。

Javascriptなんかで、Webアプリを組むときに指とApple Pencilでは別の制御でもあるんでしょうか?

どのへんでつまづいているかわかれば対策とれるかもしれないのですが

Answer (score 3):

JavaScriptなら[`PointerEvent.pointerType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent/pointerType)を見ると`"mouse"`、`"pen"`、`"touch"`の区別はできますよ。